# Rotate sprite around mouse

Tags: c++, sfml

I have been trying SFML for 3 weeks soon. I've found this thing about rotating a sprite around the mouse. From long range it looks good. But the clooser it comes the more unaccurat it becomes. My image is 960 x 540

Heres the relevant code:

```
Game::Game()
    : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(WindowWidth, WindowHeight), WindowName, sf::Style::Close)
    , mPlayerTexture()
    , mPlayer()
    , mIsMovingDown(false)
    , mIsMovingLeft(false)
    , mIsMovingRight(false)
    , mIsMovingUp(false)
 {
    if (!mPlayerTexture.loadFromFile("Media/Texture/eagle.png"))
   { }
    mPlayer.setTexture(mPlayerTexture);
    mPlayer.setScale(sf::Vector2f(0.25, 0.25));
    mPlayer.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(120.f, 135.f));
 }

 void Game::lookAtMouse(sf::RenderWindow &win)
 {
    sf::Vector2f curPos = mPlayer.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2i position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(win);

    const float PI = 3.14159265; 

    float dx = curPos.x - position.x;
    float dy = curPos.y - position.y;

    float rotation = (atan2(dy, dx)) * 180 / PI;

    mPlayer.setRotation(rotation + 180);
 }
```

Comment: SFML has the notion of an object's [origin](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a56c67bd80aae8418d13fb96c034d25ec), which is its center of rotation among other things. Is this what you're after ?

Comment: It looks like you're determining the angle of rotation by examining the current point (in screen coords?) so when you zoom in, this angle is going to increase (Edit: I'm not sure about this) causing the steps to become course. Try decreasing the angle you're rotating things by based on your 'zoom level' and see if you can't get any better results.EDIT: Trying a smaller rotation value will probably help your problem regardless of my above statement being right or wrong. Time for coffee .

Comment: I tried that but it didnt help when I had the origin in the center